# can not show result in scala using println

Tags: scala

I am developing a scala script that gives all distinct combinations of elements of an array.
For example, assume we have the `Array(1,3,6,7)`. So, the needed results should be like : `Array((1,3),(1,6),(1,7),(3,6),(3,7),(6,7))`

```
 val test : Array[Int] = Array(1,3,6,7)
  val result = test.distinct.combinations(2).flatMap{ case Array(a,b) =>
    Array((a,b))
  }
  println(result)
```

But this code does not print the needed result.

**EDIT**

For added need, the initial table should have strings and not integers(this was just for operations tests).
Asuume that I have the list val test = List("test", "tabdc", "efjh", "hlmn")
And as proposed by **@Luis Miguel Mejía Suárez**, I generated all combinaisons

```
val result: List[(String, String)] = List((test,tabdc), (test,efjh), (test,hlmn), (tabdc,efjh), (tabdc,hlmn), (efjh,hlmn))
```

using

```
val result = test.distinct.combinations(2).collect {
  case a :: b :: Nil =>
    (a, b)}.toList
```

Now, I should compare each couple generated by these pieces of code to construct a string according to these rules :

- two parts can be joined when the last character of the first part is
  equal to the first character of the second part.
- when combining two parts, only one copy of the linking character is
  kept

In other words:

- for the couple `(test,tabdc)` : we have `test` is ended by `t` and
  `tabdc` begin with `t` . So, they should be added as "**`testabdc`**"
- for the couple `((efjh,hlmn))` : we have `efjh` is ended by `h` and
  `hlmn` begin with `h` . So, they should be added as : "**`efjhlmn`**"

In this example: the final result should be **`testabdctestabdc`** (the concatenation between all joined parts)
How can I do it, please?

Comment: What if the parts can't be combined?

Comment: @Luis Miguel Mejía Suárez, there should be au minimum one couple which could be combined and other information final string should begin with `A` and finish by `Z` I add this in the question

Comment: Okey I see it. Actually the problem you are trying to solve is very far from the original question and actually `combinations` is not really the best way to solve it. - I would recommend you to revert that edit and rather open a new question with all details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okey, multiple things are happening in this snippet.

1. `combinations` returns an `Iterator` which is lazy by nature, so that is why you don't see any output; because it hasn't computed anything at all.
   You may try to solve that by adding a `toArray` at the end, but that will give you a wrong output.
2. `Arrays` should not be used, especially not while learning, they are useful for **Java** interop and performance tunning, but normal **Scala** code shouldn't wonder about those things.
   The list of reasons for not using `Arrays` include: they are mutable, they are invariant, they are not part of the collections hierarchy, their `equals` is by reference instead of by value, and their `toString` doesn't pretty print the contents of the `Array`; that is why adding a `toArray` at the end won't fix the problem. Thus, rather we should use `List` everywhere.
3. No need for that `flatMap` a simple `map` would work. However, since `combinations` can't guarantee the type safety of its output, is better to use `collect` just to be safe.

Thus the final code would be:

```scala
val test = List(1, 3, 6, 7)
val result = test.distinct.combinations(2).collect {
  case a :: b :: Nil =>
    (a, b)
}.toList
```

---

*You can see the code running [here](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/BalmungSan/bvYaQ7bAT2qzHUkKauVRoQ)*.

Comment: Hello @Luis Miguel Mejía Suárez, thank you for your response, how about if my table contains strings and wanna applicate some tests between each couple `(a,b)` to construct strings results. Please look to this link https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/273271/rebuild-message-from-strings-parts-in-scala, thank you

Comment: please look to the edited question, thank you

Comment: @GuruStron done thank you and to Luis also. But sadly, I lost the possibility to ask question

Comment: @user8810618 WDYM? You should be able to ask a new question.

Answer (score 1):

`result` is `Iterator` which is [lazy](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/collections/iterators.html#laziness), so one way to print is materialize it using `toSeq` for example:

```
println(result.toSeq) // prints List((1,3), (1,6), (1,7), (3,6), (3,7), (6,7))
```

Comment: Hello @Guru Stron, thank you if you can see the edited question and help. Thanks in advance

Comment: @user8810618 you should not be extending a question with new "tasks" - if your original problem was solved then it is almost always better to as a new one. And try solving your problems yourself, SO is not a code writing service.

Comment: Ok Ok sorry, I am just keep trying , I am beginner in scala so that I demanded help

Comment: @user8810618 no problem)